# How to build a ViennaCl project using Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: viennacl

I have successfully built ViennaCL using mingw32-make and run some of its generated tests on Windows 7 x64. When I try to build a new Viennacl project using Visual C++ 2010 Ultimate, the linker gives me the below answer:

error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo

> esterno _clGetPlatformIDs@12  non risolto nella funzione "class
>   std::vector > __cdecl viennacl::ocl::get_platforms(void)"

CODE:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <process.h>
#include <viennacl\ocl\device.hpp>
#include <viennacl\ocl\platform.hpp>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    typedef std::vector< viennacl::ocl::platform > platforms_type;
    platforms_type platforms = viennacl::ocl::get_platforms();    
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.
Sorry for the linker's italian answer.
Basically, the linker cannot to find the function _clGetPlatformIDs.
Thanks in advance.
Pietro.